# What is this? Mystic square on web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

On three of my web forms, all of them containing a gridview, I get a mystic squere right below the gridview. I have no idea what it is and where it comes from, and how I get rid of it?

Any ideas?

[image]

My ASP.NET:

```
                    <td class="auto-style43" colspan="2">
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" HeaderStyle-CssClass="HeaderStyle" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#cbe4f0" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black" Height="118px" Width="390px" GridLines="Horizontal">
                        <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField >
                         <HeaderTemplate>
                             <input id="chkAll" onclick="SelectAllCheckboxes(this);" runat="server" type="checkbox" />                                        
                         </HeaderTemplate>            
                         <ItemTemplate>
                             <asp:CheckBox ID="myCheckBox" runat="server" /> 
                         </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>                                                    
                    </asp:GridView>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style41">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="auto-style42"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style35">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnRemove" runat="server" CssClass="button" OnClick="btnRemove_Click" Text="Ta bort tider" />
                        </td>
                    <td class="auto-style35"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style35">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="auto-style35">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style35">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="auto-style35">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                </table>
        </div>
   </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: try right clicking in chrome and inspecting element yet? firefox has a similar tool as well. it should show you what is rendered, and help you find it.

Comment: Are you using the designer in Visual Studio or are you manually typing the markup? The designer can create some funky markup. Do as mmeasor suggested. Every browser, IE included, can inspect the html.

Comment: http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs132/resources/inspector/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have many webforms in the project, all of them has a table but not the weird squere under it. Only three webforms get this squere.

I'm using Visual Studio, and Firefox and IE. How can I find the inspecting link in Firefox or IE?

I'm using

Comment: I found the inspecting thing i Firefox and it tells me that the squere is this:
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"></div>

How can I remove it?

Comment: If you are using JQuery DatePicker it looks like it's broken.  You should check to see if you are getting JavaScript errors which would prevent DatePicker from loading properly.

Comment: Yes it seems like it's datepicker. But my datepicker on the page is working properly.